# Create a plot from a pandas dataframe pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table, bar-chart

I'm new to python and was wondering how to create a barplot on this data I created using pivot table function.

```
#Create a pivot table for handicaps count calculation for no-show people based on their gender 
pv = pd.pivot_table(df_main, values=['hipertension','diabetes','alcoholism'], 
                     columns='status',index='gender',aggfunc=np.sum)
#Reshape the pivot table for easier calculation 
        
data_pv = pv.unstack().unstack('status').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'category','No-Show':'no_show', 'Show-Up':'show_up'})
        
data_pv['no_show_prop'] = (data_pv['no_show']/
                          (data_pv['no_show']+data_pv['show_up']))*100
data_pv
```

And as a result:

```
status  category    gender  no_show show_up no_show_prop
0   alcoholism      F        308       915     25.183974
1   alcoholism      M        369      1768     17.267197
2   diabetes        F        1017     4589     18.141277
3   diabetes        M        413      1924     17.672229
4   hipertension    F        2657    12682     17.321859
5   hipertension    M        1115     5347     17.254720
```

I want to create a bar graph with category as x-axis and no_show_prop as y-axis with two different colors bars indicate female and male for each category. I also tried using groupby but it's not come out as I wanted to be.

Instead of bar like in this picture below, I want to create a bar graph with category as x-axis and no_show_prop as y-axis with two different colors bars indicate female and male for each category. I also tried using groupby but it's not come out as I wanted to be.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Starting with `data_pv`, reshape the data into a wide form, with [`pandas.Dataframe.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), that's easier to plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which will use the index as the x-axis, and the columns as the bar values.

- `pivot_table` if values need to be aggregated (e.g. `'sum'`)
- `pivot` if no aggregation is needed

Use `kind='bar'` for a bar plot, or `kind='line'` for a line plot. Either will work, depending on the desired plot.

```
df = data_pv.pivot(index='category', columns='gender', values='no_show_prop')
```

`df` now looks like:

```
gender                F          M
category                          
alcoholism    25.183974  17.267197
diabetes      18.141277  17.672229
hipertension  17.321859  17.254720
```

Then you can simply do:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with the dataframe in a long form using `seaborn`, which makes it very easy to make a categorized barplot, without the need to transform the dataframe to a wide format.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='category', y='no_show_prop', hue='gender', data=df)
```

[image]